# Running "ng serve" with angular CLI first time wont compile right and gives an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

So I am trying to start my first project in angular.

And every time it won't compile like it won't do `ng serve` and complete it without an error, it is hard to explain I hope you forgive that with me on that.

Basically, Im running ***node-v9.1.0*** and ***npm-v5.5.1*** on ***Windows 10 Pro 64bit***

Commands I used is `npm install -g @angular/cli` & `ng new ngvic` and the cd into the folder and using `ng serve`.

## Then I get this error:

```
λ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-11-21T09:53:09.965Z
Hash: 
Time: 2522ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 3.49 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 1.19 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 9.02 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 853 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/sites/ngvic/src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sites\ngvic\src\main.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sites\ngvic\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:619:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sites\ngvic\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/sites/ngvic/src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sites\ngvic\src\polyfills.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sites\ngvic\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:619:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\sites\ngvic\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

## And this is the `ng -v`

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.3
Node: 9.1.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.36
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.5
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Hope anyone can help with this.
Thanks in advance.

## Edit: Added tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
     "main.ts"
  ]
}
```

## Edit 2: `npm install` warns

```
λ npm install
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 115 packages in 7.541s
```

Comment: Site note I Changed folder to USERNAME instead of my PC's name.

Comment: Can you please post your `tsconfig.json` file contents?

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan Done.

Answer (score 0):

add the `main.ts` file to the `tsconfig.json` under `include` property.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
     "main.ts", 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work after trying it just says `Error: error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'include'.` thats after i removed the `,`from the ts" part

Comment: @MeickiJeldal need to add the `"compilerOptions": {},`

Comment: It's in there but do I need to put it in it or

Comment: sorry `include` should be outside of the `compilerOptions` object

Comment: its giving me this `Error: error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../main.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["test.ts","**/*.spec.ts"]'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` only in terminal. That fixed the issue for me during my first angular project

Comment: Done that too doesn't work. It runs and changes and then it gives warnings (check edit 2)

Comment: can you add  "baseUrl": "src" under compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

Comment: try running this. ``npm i -g npm-check-updates`` then

`ncu -a` and lastly 

`npm install`

Comment: if it fails, try installing angular-cli locally with this code `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Tried all of it getting this error now after i also `npm install typescript@=2.4.2` for some reason error `TS5014: Failed to parse file 'C:/Users/Melon/Dokumenter/sites/ngvic/tsconfig.json': Unexpected token } in JSON at position 361.`

Comment: it seems there is a misplaced } in tsconfig.json. can you post the updated content of the file?

Comment: Is it possible to get in contact with u so you maybe can help me directly `when u have time ?

Comment: I Havnt got enugh points to chat over here anywhere else we can chat. ?

Comment: im ok with skype. you can add me. master_voltaire

Comment: I've added u now :) my skype is meicki_dk